How to make an offline network of Raspberry Pis?
I'm building an installation with 6 Linux computers (Raspberry Pis) connected to a switch.
Right now they are connected to my home home router, that is DHCPing them an ip and all of them are happy and can see each other both IP wise 192.168.1.x and with their respective hostnames Rpi1.local -> Rpi6.local.
So some of them run a web server, other get info from them using GET requests etc…
This network should also run when I disconnect them from the router and reboot them. As soon as they are booted they automatically start looking for their peers on the network.
How can I make sure that they will connect when there is no router?
I would prefer to have them connect to each other using their hostnames. This way I will not have to change my config files.
[EDIT] here is what I've tried so far after someone pointed me in the avahi/zeroconf direction. Apparently both raspbian and ubuntu do not support ZeroConf out of the box.
I disconnected the router and rebooted the RPis. I could no longer reach them. I get a "could not resolve". As soon as I replug the router cable, they can see each other.
If I run sudo avahi-daemon I get Daemon already running on PID 683 on all RPis. When I run avahi-browse -a on one of the nodes, the others are not listed, not even when connected to the router.
I changed the publish-workstation=no line in /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf to yes and they show up under IPV6 in avahi-browse -a but I can still not ssh to them using their hostnames.
I tried switching the Ethernet interface in the RPi GUI to link-local mode. This effectively assigns a 169.254.x.x address upon reboot, but now I can no longer connect to the RPi in any way, not with the router cable connected nor disconnected.
Then I started installing avahi-autoipd on all boxes. Thios installs a daemon that is showing up  in /etc/network/interfaces.d/ as a script. I run this manually  with cable connected I see:
$ sudo avahi-autoipd eth0
Found user 'avahi-autoipd' (UID 113) and group 'avahi-autoipd' (GID 123).
Successfully called chroot().
Successfully dropped root privileges.
Starting with address 169.254.13.255
Routable address already assigned, sleeping.

when I reboot without the router connected and run sudo avahi-autoipd eth0 I get
Found user 'avahi-autoipd' (UID 113) and group 'avahi-autoipd' (GID 123).
Successfully called chroot().
Successfully dropped root privileges.
Starting with address 169.254.13.255
Callout BIND, address 169.254.13.255 on interface eth0
Successfully claimed IP address 169.254.13.255

but I still cannot connect

something on the network has to act as a DHCP server, unless you use fixed IP addresses for all of the devices

@jsotola Why can't link-local addressing work? This is exactly what it's for.

@Spiff I learn something new every day ... thanks for the lesson

@jsotola Well it turned out I was wrong and OP's Linux distro had a broken ZeroConf implementation so link-local isn't working out after all.


I tried switching the Ethernet interface in the RPi GUI to link-local mode. This effectively assigns a 169.254.x.x address upon reboot, but now I can no longer connect to the RPi in any way, not with the router cable connected nor disconnected.

Your computer needs to have an 169.254.x.x address as well. The RPi doesn't automatically know routes for any other addresses except the 169.254.x.x addresses (i.e. its own subnet).

I changed the publish-workstation=no line in /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf to yes and they show up under IPV6 in avahi-browse -a but I can still not ssh to them using their hostnames.

Hostname lookup is somewhat independent from service discovery (the former doesn't rely on the advertised "workstation" service at all). Both are handled by the same daemon, but through different mDNS entries; additionally, your RPi needs the nss_mdns module to integrate mDNS hostname lookup with the OS. (This is probably libnss-mdns on Debian.)
The hostnames always have the .local suffix. If your router's DNS happens to use the same suffix, your OS might automatically deactivate its mDNS support.

Devices with IPv4 link-local addresses are supposed to treat all subnets as local, and hosts that support IPv4 link local are supposed to always treat the 169.254.0.0/16 subnet as local, so you should never be unable to connect to a device with a 169.254 address because of a subnet mismatch. But I guess the state of ZeroConf support in these distros is in worse shape than I'd imagined. The magic is lost when your OS makes you do nonzero configuration to achieve zero configuration.

I added a keyboard to one of the pis and disconnected my main computer completely, same for the router. In the end I ended up using the second NIC of the Orange Pi 5 plus in the network to setup routing masquerading and a DHCP server.. works perfect now, but it did feel a bit overkill. Would still like to have a working local link setup for the future. I agree with @Spiff that this should work out of the box, I'm using a mix of ubuntu and raspbian, are these known to violate the zeroconf protocols?
